# Calculate sum of hours from weekly bases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to find the maximum date for that particular client, that will be treated as latest date (or current date). Then, From there I need to go back 52 weeks to 27 weeks and calculate sum(hours). And 26 Weeks to latest date (or current date) and calculate sum(hours).

```
 ClientID  StoreID    period      hours
    1       10      2010-04-19  8.04
    1       10      2010-04-20  6.24
    1       10      2010-04-21  8.26
    1       20      2010-04-22  7.94
    1       20      2010-04-23  22.43
    1       20      2010-04-24  22.99
    2       5       2010-12-19  130.67
    2       5       2010-12-26  159.26
    2       5       2011-01-02  113.59
    2       5       2011-01-09  12.66
    2       8       2011-01-16  22.34
    2       8       2011-01-23  11.35
```

Please let me know how to calculate this in SQL to get ouput ? If you have question ask me.

Comment: What have you tried?  What do you have so far?  Are you looking for a conceptual "how to I achieve this" or actual code?

Comment: Okay, based on the sample data you've provided, what output would you be expecting?

Comment: If the latest date is earlier than current date, do you want to go back 52 weeks from latest or current?  For example, if Client 1 has a latest date of 4/24, but today is 5/9, which are you counting back from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simplest to just use two queries for this; the first to get the boundary dates, the second to compute the totals.  You could roll it all into one query but I don't think it will make much of a difference.

```
DECLARE
    @BeginDate datetime,
    @MidDate datetime

SELECT
    @BeginDate = DATEADD(wk, -52, MAX(period)),
    @MidDate = DATEADD(wk, -25, MAX(period))
FROM TableName
WHERE ClientID = @ClientID

SELECT
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN period >= @BeginDate AND period < @MidDate THEN hours
            ELSE 0
        END) AS HoursInFirstHalf,
    SUM(CASE
            WHEN period >= @MidDate THEN hours
            ELSE 0
        END) AS HoursInLastHalf
FROM TableName
WHERE ClientID = @ClientID
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but from how I've read the question it's likely that the OP wants this for every client. Otherwise I think your approach is very neat. (Only it should be `27` instead of `25`.) I would probably transform the first SELECT to a subselect that would be joined back to the original table.

Comment: @Andriy: The question says *"for that particular client"*. That is the exact opposite of "for every client". If that's what the OP really meant then he stated the problem incorrectly. You're also incorrect about the week count; the OP states 27 weeks from the *begin* date, this is subtracting 25 weeks from the *end* date which is the same thing. Finally, as I said, you could roll this into one query with a subselect, but I see no benefit to doing so, it only serves to make the query less readable (maybe if this were an inline TVF it would be important).

Comment: Using a CTE wouldn't make the script less readable, in my opinion, although I understand that we can't be sure if the OP's server's version is 2005 or higher. Anyway, I was speaking about transforming to a subselect only in the context of modifying the solution to return data for all the clients. If you are staying with the single client solution then I agree, there's not much gain in transforming the first select into a subquery.

Comment: As for the number of weeks to subtract to obtain `@MidDate`, I can see now that I was wrong, but I still don't agree with the `-25` of yours. I realise that the OP's description is somewhat obscure. Still, I think it would be logical to assume that they want to return the results for the two halves of a 52-week range. My reading is, the first half starts at the week number minus 52 and lasts till the minus 27th week inclusive. Then, starting from minus 26th week till now (more exactly, till yesterday inclusive), follows the second half. So `@MidDate` should be `DATEADD(wk, -26, MAX(period))`.

Comment: @Andriy: That may be so, it's a bit hard to tell from the way the question is worded.  I'm sure that the OP can replace `25` with `26` if that is indeed the case.